# Dynamic color changing data table

Tags: python, datatables, ironpython

I have a very basic GUI that I created using Ironpython.

Inside the GUI there is a button and a table.

The goal is to click the button and after few calculations the table will be filled with the results of the calculation.

However, I had like to be able to change the color of each row depanding on its value by a simple if condition.

It is pretty general question however I couldnt find yet a post that contains all the good and simple solutions to create it, so I think it can be a good place to suggest about python dynamic tables.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Can you share the code you have?

Comment: Dont have current code however tried different modules which dont work so well in ironpython since its little problematic to import packages in it. Used html in one project as well but looking for pure python option that might require very basic modules